# How to call long methods with parameters in objective c

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

How can i call the method below manually in objective c. I need this because my button is in another class and it has to call the method of another class. And that method is a delegate method which i need to call. CAn anyone guide me in this.

Thanks in advance.

This is the method i need to call which in class A.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
int index = [self.VControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
if (index + 1 < [self.VControllers count])
{
    return [self.VControllers objectAtIndex:index + 1];
}
return nil;
}
```

Class B:

```
-(void)next
 {
exampleViewController *vc = [[exampleViewController alloc]init];
[vc pageViewController:vc.pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:vc.view];
}
```

What i need is to move the next View Controller through this method.

Comment: and how are you using this method in class a,

Comment: I've rolled back your last edit as it made the question utterly meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[instanceName pageViewController: upvc viewControllerAfterViewController: uvw];

Where instanceName is the instance of the class containing this metod,  upvc is the UIPageViewController parameter you pass along and uvw is the UIViewController parameter that you pass along.

If you want to do something with the the returned UIViewController do:

UIViewController *vc = [instanceName pageViewController: upvc viewControllerAfterViewController: uvw];

If you want to call it from a button you have to declare an IBAction method that handles the buttons touch up inside event. From the IBAction you can call this method.  So declare the IBAction in your .h

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender;
```

and in the .m implement like this

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender
{
     UIViewController *vc = [instanceName pageViewController: upvc viewControllerAfterViewController: uvw];
}
```

Comment: I am having the above mentioned method in question is in class A and button in class B. So i need to call the method that is in class A from the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can call function manually as you called to other function

In classB

```
#import "ClassA.h"
```

and make its object

```
ClassA *classA_Object = [[ClassA alloc] init];

UIViewController *ViewController = [classA_Object pageViewController:classA_Object.yourPageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:classA_Object.view];
```

According to your code you can call it as.

```
[self next]
```

and

```
-(void)next
 {
exampleViewController *vc = [[exampleViewController alloc]init];
[vc pageViewController:nil viewControllerAfterViewController:vc.view];
}
```

Comment: I am having the above mentioned method in question is in class A and button in class B. So i need to call the method that is in class A from the button.

Comment: iam not getting what parameters to pass here.

Comment: I am calling this way: [self pageViewController: pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:viewController];

Comment: is pageViewController and yourViewController are using in this method??

Comment: the page view controller is defined and implemented in class A and both are using in this method.

Comment: can your please paste the full code of pageViewController method ofclassA

Comment: ya sure just give mefew mins